# Android Studio: Keep project file tree state expanded

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am using the latest version of Android Studio. Every time I close Android Studio or start debugging/executing the project, the "Project Files" tree collapses.

Is there a setting to keep the tree expanded in the current state or to expand the whole tree again?

Comment: Don't use `Project Files` section. Use `Android` or just `Project`. They shouldn't collapse. Command+1 is the shortcut to open Project page.

Comment: Thanks. Funny that I missed that...

Comment: Did it actually work? Should I make it and asnwer for you to accept?

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly. Please make it an answer.

Comment: On the windows platform - the Android tree is collapsed at startup - but the tabs are still persisted.   I can't seem to find a shortcut to open the tree at the tab path.   So I filled an enhancement request:  [http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222172](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=222172)

Comment: Thanks; I switched to Project and it saved the expanded folders (THANK GOD). However, I was actually previously using Android in the project drop down and that did not save the expanded folders. I'm using Android Studio v3.5.2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `Project Files` section. Use `Android` or just `Project` sections. They shouldn't collapse.

**PS:** Also `Command+1` is the shortcut to open Project page.

Comment: How is that not a bug?

Comment: I use Android and everything is collapsed each time I start the app

Comment: Seems to be a bug to me too, as Android view now collapses when building / running a project. The only thing I've found thus far is to enable Autoscroll from Source in the Project tab settings as shown in the following image [link](http://imgur.com/a/ZaIuT). This will expand the tree to show the file you are currently viewing in editor, which is better than nothing.

Answer (score 10):

Very annoying. You can solve it by clicking the gear icon, and select `Autoscroll from source`. Then, anytime you select a tab, it will expand and select the file in the tree view.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- Expand the packages
- Click gear icon at the top
- Untick `Compact Middle Packages`